# he had two dimes to rub together from looking at his house or the car he drove

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The retired police chief smiled and told me that "whatever he did in other places he kept it out of our juris-diction. He was old-school, very polite, a perfect gentleman. You wouldn't know he had two dimes to rub together from looking at his house or the car he drove.

Did he collect a minimum amount of money from people who looked at his house or car? Or he didn't want anything more than his car and house, right?

Comment: https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=WNRI4PuS9GMC&pg=PT69&lpg=PT69&dq=he+had+two+dimes+to+rub+together+from+looking+at+his+house+or+the+car+he+drove&source=bl&ots=Yiq4f0tAgA&sig=ACfU3U1GwBMrJbQA4LyGucwOP-x_tF515A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYmIqxotXnAhWB3mEKHQBvD8kQ6AEwAnoECAUQAQ

Comment: The usual expression here has been flipped. “He *didn’t* have two dimes to rub together” means he had no money, but I think this is trying to say he *did* have plenty of money and you wouldn’t know it by looking at his house and car (implying that his house and car are inexpensive looking, not impressive).

Comment: This American English expression has a British English version using different coins (pennies, farthings, etc.).  In Australian English we say “he didn’t have a brass razoo”: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass_razoo

Comment: In Britain, even now, approx 50 years after currency decimalisation, you hear people saying that someone, obviously not poor, has 'a bob or two'. A 'bob' was a shilling, twelve pre-decimal pence. There were 240 of these to a pound.